# Magic Keyboard FN Keys on Windows 11

Tags: keyboard, windows

Any way to get FN/media keys to work? I have an A2450 Magic Keyboard 2.

Tried some older bootcamp drivers but it doesn't seem to work.
Tried brigadier and .inf drivers from [here](https://github.com/AbsentForeskin/Apple-Input-Device-Drivers-Windows-10-11).

Opening .inf in notepad shows they are drivers for older models of the Magic Keyboard than the one I own.

(Magic Keyboard Utilities app makes it flawless, but it has a costly subscription.)

Comment: Hey, the method explained in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FXf75lUuqWM) is said to be working with the A2450 keyboard, have you tried it?

Comment: Yes that's the one I tried. In the last part, I can't find the same key in regedit. There are other comments mentioning this too without solution found. I personally might have done something wrong, and would be happy to try any instructions again if someone confirms it works for them with Win11 + A2450 or A2449 (touch ID)